# Force application to run with optional DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have made desktop application. I have make class library and then make its DLL from University assembly. Now i want to make library DLL optional. In short i want to run the application weather or not library DLL is refereed.

Right now if i remove reference of library DLL then it gives error on library methods that they are not defined. I want this application to run with oujt giving error of library method.

I have search on google but i am unable to find out any reliable answer.

Comment: no its not duplicate. What i want is to run an application with out giving refference to DLL

Comment: I don't see a point here. If you are calling methods from an external DLL in you ought to refer to it. What do you expect compiler to do? Ignore blatant mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if assembly exists on disk, and if it's true use dynamic assembly loading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx

Called classes/methods in your library can be replaced by stubs(new level of abstraction), in which you can check if assembly is successfully loaded, and invoke from it if yes.

Ok.. Very simple example:

"Real Assembly" code(First project, compiled as class library "RealAssembly.dll"):

```
namespace RealAssembly
{
    using System;
    public class RealClass
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        public int SomeProperty { get { return rand.Next(); } }

        public string SomeMethod()
        {
            return "We used real library! Meow!";
        }
    }
}
```

"Our project" code with Fake(stub) class(Second project, compiled as Console applicaiton - "ClientApp.exe"):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ClientApp
{
    class FakeClass
    {
        public int SomeProperty { get { return 0; } }

        public string SomeMethod()
        {
            return "Library not exists, so we used stub! :)";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        // dynamic instance of Real or Fake class
        private static dynamic RealOfFakeObject;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TryLoadAssembly();
            Console.WriteLine(RealOfFakeObject.SomeMethod());
            Console.WriteLine(RealOfFakeObject.SomeProperty);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void TryLoadAssembly()
        {
            string assemblyFullName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "RealAssembly.dll");

            if (File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
            {
                var RealAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFullName);
                var RealClassType = RealAssembly.GetType("RealAssembly.RealClass");
                RealOfFakeObject = Activator.CreateInstance(RealClassType);
            }
            else
            {
                RealOfFakeObject = new FakeClass();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This two projects are not referenced directly. "System" is the only reference used in this two projects.

So now, if compiled "RealAssembly.dll" exists in same directory we will have "We used real library! Meow!" string and random integer at console output. Otherwise if "RealAssembly.dll" not exists in same directory - "Library not exists, so we used stub! :)" and 0 will be shown.

Comment: thanks for reply. But what i want is that i dunt reffer to assembly and my application dont give error.

Comment: This is a way to do this.

You don't need to reference assembly directly in project "references" - instead you need to check in your code at runtime if assembly "dll" exists on disk somewhere, and if it exist(or for example after user pressed some "Load University Library" button) - load it.

If library not exists - code will use new classes(must be written) which will invoke code from dynamically loaded assembly if it loaded.

If you want, i even can show simple example..

Comment: but if DLL dont exist then it should not give error

Comment: yeah. it looks almost that i got an answer. but i need your help in last step. Assembly.loadfrom method is giving error if it could not found an assembly. is there any way that it should return null if it could not find an assembly

Comment: Yes. Just don't call it if assembly file not found! :) I used "File.Exists" method for purpose of checking of that situation.

After you check if that assembly DLL exists or not, you can do whatever you want to do...