# Delay loaded DLLs - what am I missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Under the Linker Input options in MS Visual Studio (several versions) is the field `Delay Loaded DLLs`. How exactly does this work?

When I specify "mydll.dll" in this field, I consistently get a warning of `no imports found from mydll.dll` but when I run my executable, it complains that it cannot find mydll.dll (suggesting it does have a need to import something from it) and I am forced to exit the program.

My best guess is that I should specify both "mydll.lib" under the `Additional Dependencies`, and then specify either "mydll.dll" or "mydll.lib" in the `Delay Loaded DLLs` file according to what works. So far no combination I have tried works, and nothing shines explicit enough light on exactly how it should be used. Help!

Secondary question open for comment (not answer): this is being done in the context of a custom image processing application which can run both from a live camera source, or from pre-recorded video playback from disk. When no camera DLL is present, we want to be able to run, but restrict the input source to pre-recorded video only. Is using a delay loaded DLL a reasonable way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

For each delay loaded library, link the library normally (alongside any other required libraries) by including it in the `Additional Dependencies`. Also include the library `DelayImp.lib`: e.g. "thislib.lib thatlib.lib otherlib.lib DelayImp.lib"

Now specify each delay loaded library under `Delay Loaded DLLs` using its DLL name, and separating multiple entries with semi-colons, e.g. "thislib.dll;thatlib.dll"

Compile (if necessary), link (necessary), enjoy. No additional confusing `#pragma` code suggested by both [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf3f62bz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [this CodeProject explanation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9428/Delay-Loading-a-DLL) is necessary.

As for whether this is a reasonable way to cope with situations where DLLs are in effect optional, people will have their opinions. But it certainly seems much simpler than using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` manually, or creating some kind of dummy DLL which is deployed in a folder further down the search path than the DLL would normally be found. It is also vastly simpler to [this approach which is applicable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343052/force-application-to-run-with-optional-dll). Those are the only alternatives of which I am aware.